# How to use gtag.js to pass parameters so they show up as Dimensions in google data studio

Tags: looker-studio, gtag.js

i have set up gtag.js and i am able to send custom events and view them in the data studio.

However i do not know how to pass custom properties so the names and values of these show up in the data studio and i can "select" them for a graph.

my sample code is the following

```
window.gtag('event', 'Old Layout',     {
    event_category: 'Layout changes',
    event_action: 'change layout',
    event_label: 'switch to old layout',
    event_value: $(this).prop('checked'),});
```

but when i try to select dimensions it only gives me "event name" and "is conversion event".

How should i pass the custom properties so i can select as "dimension"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the properties as custom dimensions or metrics in the Configure->Custom definitions section. If you then refresh the fields in the data source, they should show up.

You can use more descriptive properties in GA4. And use their naming convention so your events will be usable. e.g.

```js
window.gtag('event', 'layout_changed', {
    layout_used: $(this).prop('checked') ? 'new' : 'old'
});
```